# How to Send proper html data to iphone from php?

Tags: php, iphone, cakephp

I am sending mail content to iPhone mobile using Cakephp function. Mail successfully sends to iPhone but the content they receive is in an uneven format.

Exampe: My Content

```
  Username:siddesh
  Date:2013-06-20 04:46:40
  Email:siddesh@bhalke.com
  Type:seller
  File Name:xlsfile
  File Type:xls
  Uploaded By:primary User
  Download :[download]
```

My Code:

```
  <p>Username:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username);?></p>
  <p>Date:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date);?></p>
  <p>Email:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email);?></p>
  <p>Type:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($type);?></p>
  <p>File Name:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($file_name);?></p>
  <p>File Type:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($file_type);?></p>
  <p>Uploaded By:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($uploaded_by);?></p>
  <p><a href="<?php echo 'http://www.test.com/files/'.$uid.'/'.$file_name.'.'.$file_type;?>">Download</a></p><br/>
```

Should receive Format:

```
  Username:siddesh
  Date:2013-06-20 04:46:40
  Email:siddesh@bhalke.com
  Type:seller
  File Name:xlsfile
  File Type:xls
  Uploaded By:primary User
  Download :[download]
```

But It received Format on iPhone as:
SUBJ:test-failed file

```
MSG:¿¿¿¿¿¿                                                   





(Con't) 2 of 6




(Con't) 3 of 6






Username:Rajesh:2013-06-17
10:05:14Email:sid@r

(Con't) 4 of 6

mygroup.comType:MyFile
Name:simple Type:xlsUploaded By:Sid blk
ConnectionThank

(Con't) 5 of 6

You,test.com





    A¿ Copyright
2013 by test. All Right Reserved.


  info@test.com

  www.test.com
```

Send Mail Function..!

```
    function sendMail($template = null, $to_email = null, $from_email = null, $subject = null, $contents = array()) {


    $from_email = Configure::read('site.support_email');
    $bcc_email = Configure::read('site.developers_email');

    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $result = $email->template($template, 'default')
            ->emailFormat('html')
            ->to($to_email)
            ->bcc($bcc_email)
            ->from($from_email)
            ->subject($subject)
            ->viewVars($contents);

    if ($email->send('default')) {
        $this->log('email to :  '  .$to_email. 'Subject :  '   .$subject);  
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

To send the above format data, I have used normal `p` and `br` tags but the data showing on iPhone is not in a proper format and few unnecessary data is sent with it.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: @AD7six: Check i have edited my question ..!!

Comment: //Send as 'html', 'text' or 'both' (default is 'text')
    $this->Email->sendAs = 'both'; // because we like to send pretty mail

Comment: @AD7six : Now i have added code please check it, how can i fix it..!!

Comment: @AD7six:  Now I have written it fully, Now can u help me on this ?

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke It's not possible to say - how can one reproduce your problem? Where is all that extra text defined? What does the raw-email content look like (you'll probably need to read the mail in a different client to get this)?

Comment: -1 as the question is still incomplete. E.g. the string "Sub:" is not even in "But It received Format on iPhone as:" i.e. it's impossible to relate the code provided to the result (much less determine where all the other text comes from).

Comment: AD7six : Now I have  pasted my exact thing as you required. sry earlier i just put an example, now this time i pasted my whole code, hope you help me this time..!!

Answer (score 0):

Send the mail as HTML, instead of text like this:

```
//Send as 'html', 'text' or 'both' (default is 'text')
$this->Email->sendAs = 'both';
```

Comment: KAsh: I have added my code now, where can i edit it, please suggest..!!

Comment: except that's not sending it as html - it' sending it as both html _and_ text (which incidentally is a good practice) However it doesn't look relevant here - from the question, it's already being sent as html.